# Issue in UITableViewCell while run on iOS7?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I made app for iOS6, and as I run this on iOS7, so it disturbed my design outlook.

My Cell Code is as followed.

```
@interface Cell_ClubOffer : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *titleName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *description;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *distance;


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellImageView;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *plainButton;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *backImageView;


@end


@implementation Cell_ClubOffer

@synthesize cellImageView;
@synthesize plainButton;
@synthesize backgroundView;
@synthesize backImageView;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Now my Cell Looks like as in iOS6

[image: iOS6]

and on iOS7, it looks bad, like

[image: iOS7]

What is proper way to migrate it from iOS6 to iOS7, simply.

Comment: Say formal, what is the issue in iOS 7? I found only difference is that `plainButton` moved to the right. If so, check `UITableViewCell`s `ContentView` frame.

Comment: should i do it in CellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Set Show the size inspector of your cell left and top. And check it

Comment: Not only the button but set all the objects properties left and top